# Workout the string format used for DateTime formatting

Tags: c#, datetime, parsing, string-formatting

I have a string which represents a DataTime value, and I want to workout what string format was used to create the string.

For example
- Given "Wednesday 27 Jan 2010" I expect "dddd dd MMM yyyy"
- Given "2010 01 27" I expect "yyyy MM dd"

Assume that the date is close to DateTime.Now and relates to the CurrentCulture. So given that we have en-GB culture
- Given "01 01 2010" I expect "dd MM yyyy"

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Sorry to ask Sophie88, but why are you looking to do this?

Comment: (Possibly) dumb comment, but you know you can pass any of those dates to DateTime.Parse (or TryParse) and it will correctly parse the date? However I assume you need to return the dates in the form they're passed to you, hence you need to know the format they arrive in.

Comment: Im parsing some output from an old program for my uncle and want to know that "Wednesday" can be ignored as it's a "dddd" part.

Comment: Referring to @Binary Worrier's comment above, it can be ignored if you just use DateTime.Parse as that will try to parse the date using all valid string formats. If you want to reduce the old output to a consistent form then parse it using DateTime and output it using your defined format.

Comment: what are you getting from the "old program" a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could split on whitespace to get an array of strings
then you could test the elements in the array against known values to try to guess the format

e.g. if you search for "Wednesday" if you find it assume "dddd"

if a four digit number assume yyyy

days and months could be a problem, you could test for > 12 for the days but that's pretty bad

maybe you could infer the format using whitespace split then DateTime.Parse on the orignal and test against a formatted (using the infered format) version of the parsed date for equality

Comment: With the current culture, I can check the names of the Days of week somehow?

Comment: you could make an assumption about the order of two digit days and months based on the current culture but the "old software" might not be respecting the current culture anyway

Comment: @Sophie88: yes, you can use the DateTimeFormat property of the CultureInfo class which has itself a property called DayNames which returns a list of the day names for that culture.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to do is look at [the reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for datetime formatting strings and working them out.

You may be able to use reflection in order to get this, or use disassembler (such as [ILDASM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1(VS.80).aspx)) to find all the strings used in an assembly and guess at which ones are datetime formatting string.

If disassmbling, you can search for the days of the week and for a string starting with `dddd`, which should tell you how the original was constructed.